# how to change a box's color in a grid back and forth from black and white

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 5x5 grid and what I'm able to do so far is only change the color of a box one way from white to black, but I need it to alternate between black and white every time I click on the box.

Frankly I'm stumped and don't know how to make it alternate I tried to find other examples but I couldn't find any. Currently the following javascript code can only change the box color from white to black.

```
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

Array.from(grid).forEach(click => click.addEventListener("click", function() {v.style.background = "black";}));
```

Comment: I entered the code wrong on the line that says v.style.background it's supposed to be click.style.background, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some conditional checking before applying the css styles.

```js
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

Array.from(grid).forEach(click => click.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (click.style.background === 'black') {
        click.style.background = "white";
    } else {
        click.style.background = "black";
    }
}));
```